# How to download libreoffice dictionaries programmatically?

Tags: libreoffice

Is there a link where I can find all dictionaries used by libreoffice, organized by language code, so that I can download them with python script?
Is this the right place? https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

OK My bad. The dictionaries are indeed sitting at: `https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries`. Then, look for files that end with `*.dic`. For example, `el_GR.dic` for Modern Greek, `en_US.dic` for English US and so on so forth.